# Combine mp4 files by order based on number from filenames in Python

Tags: python, ffmpeg, operating-system, subprocess

I try to merge lots of `mp4` files from a directory `test` into one `output.mp4` using `ffmpeg` in Python.

```
import os

path = '/Users/x/Documents/test'

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if filename.endswith(".mp4"):
        print(filename)
```

Output:

```
4. 04-unix,minix,Linux.mp4
6. 05-Linux.mp4
7. 06-ls.mp4
5. 04-unix.mp4
9. 08-command.mp4
1. 01-intro.mp4
3. 03-os.mp4
8. 07-minux.mp4
2. 02-os.mp4
10. 09-help.mp4
```

I have tried with the solution below from the reference here: [ffmpy concatenate multiple files with a file list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53230945/ffmpy-concatenate-multiple-files-with-a-file-list)

```
import os
import subprocess
import time


base_dir = "/path/to/the/files"
video_files = "video_list.txt"
output_file = "output.avi"

# where to seek the files
file_list = open(video_files, "w")

# remove prior output
try:
    os.remove(output_file)
except OSError:
    pass

# scan for the video files
start = time.time()
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(base_dir):
    for video in files:
        if video.endswith(".avi"):
            file_list.write("file './%s'\n" % video)
file_list.close()

# merge the video files
cmd = ["ffmpeg",
       "-f",
       "concat",
       "-safe",
       "0",
       "-loglevel",
       "quiet",
       "-i",
       "%s" % video_files,
       "-c",
       "copy",
       "%s" % output_file
       ]

p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

fout = p.stdin
fout.close()
p.wait()

print(p.returncode)
if p.returncode != 0:
    raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(p.returncode, cmd)

end = time.time()
print("Merging the files took", end - start, "seconds.")
```

I have merged them and get an `output.mp4` but the files are not merged in order with the first number split by point (`1, 2, 3, ...`): which I can get by `filename.split(".")[0]`:

```
1. 01-intro.mp4
2. 02-os.mp4
3. 03-os.mp4
4. 04-unix,minix,Linux.mp4
5. 04-unix.mp4
6. 05-Linux.mp4
7. 06-ls.mp4
8. 07-minux.mp4
9. 08-command.mp4
10. 09-help.mp4
```

How can I merge them correctly and concisely in Python? Thanks.

Comment: OK what order are the merged files in? Is it random? Oh and how are expecting your process to handle the two files numbered '04'?

Comment: I hope to merge files based on order only by the number in front of the first period from filenames (at this case, it's from 1 to 10) and they are unique.

Comment: Yeah you have answered the second part of my question, the more important part is the first part concerning the order you are getting now.

Comment: Am I missing something or are you literally asking how to sort a list?

Comment: @Paula Thomas, it's not random, it's order same as output from `for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if filename.endswith(".mp4"):
        print(filename)`

Comment: @Aran-Fey Yes, kind of. I want merge files into one file and its content is in order `1. 01-intro.mp4
2. 02-os.mp4
3. 03-os.mp4
4. 04-unix,minix,Linux.mp4
5. 04-unix.mp4
6. 05-Linux.mp4
7. 06-ls.mp4
8. 07-minux.mp4
9. 08-command.mp4
10. 09-help.mp4`

Comment: OK so the problem with that is? Sorry cut that! Me being daft!

Comment: The actual file's content order is: `4. 04-unix,minix,Linux.mp4
6. 05-Linux.mp4
7. 06-ls.mp4
5. 04-unix.mp4
9. 08-command.mp4
1. 01-intro.mp4
3. 03-os.mp4
8. 07-minux.mp4
2. 02-os.mp4
10. 09-help.mp4`

Comment: OK this is me not being daft. Where do you think you've sorted the list of files? I can't see it!

Comment: I haven't add it. Maybe integrate at here is appropriate: `start = time.time()
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(base_dir):
    for video in files:
        if video.endswith(".avi"):
            file_list.write("file './%s'\n" % video)
file_list.close()`

Comment: Can't see a sort in there...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196098/discussion-between-ahbon-and-paula-thomas).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This solution works:

```
from moviepy.editor import *
import os
from natsort import natsorted

L = []

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/path/to/the/files"):

    #files.sort()
    files = natsorted(files)
    for file in files:
        if os.path.splitext(file)[1] == '.mp4':
            filePath = os.path.join(root, file)
            video = VideoFileClip(filePath)
            L.append(video)

final_clip = concatenate_videoclips(L)
final_clip.to_videofile("output.mp4", fps=24, remove_temp=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import glob
import os
 
def concatenate():
  global stringa
  stringa = "ffmpeg -i \"concat:"
  elenco_video = glob.glob("*.mp4")
  elenco_file_temp = []
  for f in elenco_video:
    file = "temp" + str(elenco_video.index(f) + 1) + ".ts"
    os.system("ffmpeg -i " + f + " -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts " + file)
    elenco_file_temp.append(file)
  print(elenco_file_temp)
  for f in elenco_file_temp:
    stringa += f
    if elenco_file_temp.index(f) != len(elenco_file_temp)-1:
      stringa += "|"
    else:
      stringa += "\" -c copy  -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc output.mp4"
  print(stringa)
  os.system(stringa)
```

this will create a concatenated video file named `output.mp4` in the working directory,,
[code source](https://pythonprogramming.altervista.org/concatenate-mp4-videos-of-different-size-with-python-and-ffmpeg/?doing_wp_cron=1612392468.6865010261535644531250)

Answer (score 1):

My videos got crossed up and blurred due to different frame sizes.. to avoid that you can use this. It was only a change to this line:

```
final_clip = concatenate_videoclips(L,method='compose')
```

which adds all the clips together despite the different frame sizes. Heres the full code:

```
from moviepy.editor import *
import os
from natsort import natsorted

def combine_videos_folder_to_one(folder_path):
    L =[]
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folder_path):
        #files.sort()
        files = natsorted(files)
        for file in files:
            if os.path.splitext(file)[1] == '.mp4':
                filePath = os.path.join(root, file)
                video = VideoFileClip(filePath)
                L.append(video)

    final_clip = concatenate_videoclips(L,method='compose')
    final_clip.to_videofile("compilation_output.mp4", fps=60, remove_temp=False)
    

combine_videos_folder_to_one(folder_videos)
```