# how to merge all video files in a directory using Moviepy [solved]

Tags: python, moviepy

I am trying to code a program that takes video files from a dir and merges them using moviepy.

Sth like that:

dir: file1, file2, file3

`final_video = concatenate_videoclips(dir)`

found an answer: [Combine mp4 files by order based on number from filenames in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56920546/combine-mp4-files-by-order-based-on-number-from-filenames-in-python)

Comment: Wouldn’t you just load each file in the directory as a `VideoFileClip` and then pass the list to `concatenate_videoclips`? What issues are you having?

Comment: OK, so you know the function to use, which is the hard part.  All  you need is a list of file names.  I assume you can figure out how to get a list of file names from a directory, can't you?

Comment: @Shunya yes, it does ^^